# Saturating BJT with phototransistor

Tags: bjt, phototransistor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiFOL4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to get a phototransistor to saturate a BJT so that when a small amount of light is present, the BJT is on. At the moment, there needs to be a lot more light than I would like, so I've been looking for a way to change how much light I need. One thing I've tried is to put two of the phototransistors in series along with a resistor, and found that by pointing one away from the light, I can get a large enough voltage across one of them to saturate the BJT with a small enough amount of light. However, put the BJT B-E in parallel, and the voltage jumps down to below what is needed. I've tried using a resistor in series with the B-E junction, but it still requires the same amount of light as before.
Any suggestions?
Sorry about the poor schematic. I couldn't find any phototransistors, so I used BJT + arrows instead.
Also, it doesn't need to be a bjt, I could get something else if it would work better.

Comment: Draw a circuit of what you tried.

Comment: WHat do you have for a collector resistor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way instead.....

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVS6WU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: With the phototransistor backwards?

Comment: @JoeP photo-diode..yes. Light causes it to leak.

Comment: Works perfectly! But it's a phototransistor - the schematic says diode because I couldn't find a phototransistor. I don't understand why it works either - how is the phototransistor supposed to behave backwards?

Comment: @JoeP perhaps I am confused by your description. try redrawing it using regular transistors with a couple of arrows to indicate its optical.

Comment: Done. Well, very curious, but at least it's put a happy end to a very stressful few hours.